# Trying to combine cols with the same name, and making the observation into new rows

Tags: r, merge, pipe

Hi I am trying to combine column names with the same name. Here is part of my data.

```
                 EL SALVADOR  HONDURAS  NICARAGUA   GUATEMALA   GUATEMALA
    TOTAL_CBP     18.00000    16.00000  7.00000     17.00000    9.00000
```

I want to combine the Guatemala cols and make a new row to place the data in with NA in the other cols.

Right now it is a data frame. Trying to keep it that way.

I am trying to do this with piping but if there is another way you would recommend please let me know. Thank you !

Comment: You can try `un1 <- unique(colnames(m1)); do.call(cbind, lapply(un1, function(x) c(m1[, colnames(m1) == x])))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method assuming that it is a `matrix`

```
un1 <- unique(colnames(m1))
lst1 <- setNames(lapply(un1, function(x)  unname(c(m1[, colnames(m1) == x]))), un1)
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
#     EL SALVADOR HONDURAS NICARAGUA GUATEMALA
#[1,]          18       16         7        17
#[2,]          NA       NA        NA         9
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(18, 16, 7, 17, 9), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    "TOTAL_CBP", c("EL SALVADOR", "HONDURAS", "NICARAGUA", "GUATEMALA", 
    "GUATEMALA")))
```

Comment: I currently have it as a data frame

Comment: @lbevs it should work for that also.  just  change the `c(m1` or `unlist(m1`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split.default` to split columns with similar names, create a one-column dataframe for each list, make the input of same length and convert to dataframe.

```
list_df <- lapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(x) 
                  setNames(data.frame(unlist(x)), names(x)[1]))
max_len <- max(sapply(list_df, nrow))
data.frame(sapply(list_df, function(x) x[1:max_len, ]))

#  EL.SALVADOR GUATEMALA HONDURAS NICARAGUA
#1          18        17       16         7
#2          NA         9       NA        NA
```